# Не работает strtotime

Tags: php

В поле формы вводится дата и время в формате d/m/Y H именно эту дату нужно преобразоваь в число, strtotimeне работает. Я везде читал что не верный формат даты. Если поменять день и месяц местами и убрать H, тогда strtotime  срабатывает, но мне нужно так же преобразовать и часы, без минут и секунд, но, strtotime не преобразовывает. Как исправть?

Comment: Используйте http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H', '2017/06/12 15');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку что функция getTimestamp не является объектом

Comment: покажи оригинальную ошибку и кусок своего кода